# Reactive Extensions, Akavache and Refit is too much for Windows Phone's Internal Card

Tags: windows-phone, system.reactive, reactiveui, akavache, refit

I want to use [paulcbetts/refit](https://github.com/paulcbetts/refit) in my application and [akavache/Akavache](https://github.com/akavache/Akavache).

Problem is that according to my logic, Windows Phone doesn't like that I do the following:

I get semester (from cache, then fetch), pick the wanted semester (I put H2014 for testing), get the schedule for the selected (Many) Semester (from cache, then fetch, as following:

```
var defer = Observable.Defer(() =>
    BlobCache.Secure.GetAndFetchLatest("Semesters", () => _api.GetSemesters())
        .Select(x => x.Single(semester => semester.AbredgedName == "H2014"))
        .SelectMany(currentSemester => BlobCache.Secure.GetAndFetchLatest("Schedule_" + currentSemester.AbredgedName,
            () => _api.GetSchedule(currentSemester.AbredgedName)))
        );

defer.Subscribe(scheduleVms => {
    foreach (var activity in scheduleVms)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("1 {0}", activity.Name);
    }
});

Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4)).Subscribe(_ =>
{
    defer.Subscribe(scheduleVms => {
        foreach (var activity in scheduleVms)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("2 {0}", activity.Name);
        }
    });
});
```

If I use a TimeSpan.FromSeconds of 5 or more, it does what I want, as if I give Windows Phone the time to breathe. Else (Under 5-ish), what I get as an exception is the following:

Exception thrown: 'System.NotSupportedException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
StackTrace:

```
at MS.Internal.Modern.InternalNetworkStream.BeginRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.IO.Stream.<BeginEndReadAsync>b__d(Stream stream, ReadWriteParameters args, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncTrim[TInstance,TArgs](TInstance thisRef, TArgs args, Func`5 beginMethod, Func`3 endMethod)
at System.IO.Stream.BeginEndReadAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at System.IO.Stream.ReadAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.DelegatingStream.ReadAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.DelegatingStream.ReadAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.IO.Stream.<CopyToAsyncInternal>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Refit.RequestBuilderImplementation.<>c__DisplayClass2a`1.<<buildCancellableTaskFuncForMethod>b__29>d__2c.MoveNext()
```

Wanted behavior:

1. Get Cached Semester -> Get Cached Schedule for that semester, Fetch Schedule for that Semester
2. Fetch Semester -> Get Cached Schedule for that semester, Fetch Schedule for that Semester

I tried:

- Chaining [akavache/Akavache](https://github.com/akavache/Akavache) without Refit and it works.
- Chaining Selects of the GetSchedule and GetSemesters without [akavache/Akavache](https://github.com/akavache/Akavache) and it works.

If you guys would have an idea on a work-arround or something I am doing wrong, let me know!

Comment: Did you managed to fix it?